# Purely algebraic proof of stable commutator length in a finitely generated solvable group

Tags: group-theory, infinite-groups

I've been asked to give a proof that a finitely generated solvable group always has vanishing stable commutator length, as a part of an assignment for an infinite groups course.

I think the way to proceed is to use induction on derived length, taking the metabelian case as the base case for the induction.

I've only come across [proofs](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/some-notes-on-amenability/) using the fact that solvable groups are amenable groups, but these haven't been defined in this course.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "has stable commutator length?" Do you mean that scl is positive for some element? This would be false.

Comment: Hi, sorry I meant vanishing stable commutator length. I have edited this now